# how to get entities with many to may dependency

Tags: sql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

This is project entity which I need to get by current user Id:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "project")
public class Project implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(name = "project_user",
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="projects_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="users_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
  private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
}
```

this is user entity whichs Id I'll use to get products:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "jhi_user")
public class User extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users")
  private Set<Project> projects = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Repositories classes extend JpaRepository class. How I can get all projects for current user Id?

Native SQL statement that I can use is:

```
SELECT * FROM project WHERE id IN (SELECT projects_id FROM project_user WHERE users_id = ?);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as simple as this...

```
User user = userRepository.findById(100L);
Set<Projects> projects = user.getProjects();
```

Because of your mapping, JPA takes care of the rest.